# Feedback or save queries from FT.AGGREGATE

Tags: database, csv, redis, nosql, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to replicate the following SQL query in rediSearch:

```
%%sql
SELECT NumQuestions, COUNT(OwnerUserId) AS NumUsers
FROM (
    SELECT OwnerUserId, COUNT(*) AS NumQuestions
    FROM Posts
    WHERE PostTypeId = 1
    GROUP BY OwnerUserId
) AS PreguntasPorUsuario
GROUP BY NumQuestions
ORDER BY NumQuestions
LIMIT 34;
```

I've managed to replicate the internal SELECT as follows:

```
%%bash
redis-cli FT.AGGREGATE postsIndex \
  "@PostTypeId:[1 1]" \
  GROUPBY 1 @OwnerUserId \
  REDUCE COUNT 0 AS NumPreguntas
```

The problem is when I try to apply a COUNT to OwnerUserId as I did in SQL. I am not able to apply it.

I have tried to store the information from my rediSearch query to use it in another query but I am not able to do it either.

If more context or information is needed I am happy to provide it. I am using Google Collab and redis-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RediSearch's `COUNT` reducer doesn't take any parameter. In SQL, giving a parameter to `COUNT` drops from the row count rows that miss a value for this field.
With RediSearch, you just would need to filter out rows that miss a value for the given field.

```bash
FT.AGGREGATE postsIndex "@PostTypeId:[1 1]" 
                        GROUPBY 1 @OwnerUserId REDUCE COUNT 0 AS NumQuestions
                        FILTER "exists(@OwnerUserId)"
                        GROUPBY 1 @NumQuestions REDUCE COUNT 0 AS NumUsers
                        SORTBY 1 @NumQuestions MAX 34
```

In your case you filter by a group value, so unless you expect a group of `NULL` you can also drop the filter step, because any other row will pass it anyway.

I think that what you’re maybe looking for is `COUNT_DISTINCT`. In RediSearch query language, `COUNT` reducer counts the number of rows under each group, while `COUNT_DISTINCT` (and `COUNT_DISTINCTISH`) counts the number of unique values in a specific field.

If that's what you wanted to query, try:

```bash
FT.AGGREGATE postsIndex "@PostTypeId:[1 1]" 
                        GROUPBY 1 @OwnerUserId REDUCE COUNT 0 AS NumQuestions
                        GROUPBY 1 @NumQuestions 
                                  REDUCE COUNT_DISTINCT 1 @OwnerUserId AS NumUsers
                        SORTBY 1 @NumQuestions MAX 34
```

I hope this answer your question. Check out the [aggregation documentations](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/advanced-concepts/aggregations/) for more info and examples of filtering and reducing